# Using IF statements to reduce no of Loop iterations

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

variable 'size' is the size of the larger list.

```
for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){

if(employees!= null && employees.size() > x){
//do something
}

if(consultants!= null && consultants.size() > x){ 
// do something
}
```

Then i have another way of doing it

```
for(Object obj : employees){
//do something
}

for(Object obj : consultants){
//do something
}
```

The second approach seems simpler to me,  but the first approach would result in lower loop iterations. anyways, i would like to know which would be better in a general situation.

Comment: This question is going to get flagged, because it's an opinion question.  But in general, the best answer is, whichever is likely to be easier for the next programmer after you to interpret.  Which means the second way is better.  Don't bother optimizing unless you have a working application that needs optimizing in this area.

Comment: This question would be better fit for sites like [Code Review Stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is size in the first loop?

Comment: Is this a proven performance trouble spot in a hot loop? If not, then which one would make more sense when you're reading it 6 months from now in your actual code? That's where I would go with this.

Comment: agree with the second, simpler method. i would suggest the extra logic you have to put into the single loop is actually slower, and definitely more problematic, than using two regular loops

Comment: oh, and i think i see a bug. under consultants you have "do something". ...hang on, i'm a consultant :)

Comment: Assuming `size = (consultants.size() > employees.size() ? consultants.size() : employees.size()` the first option would result in more bytecode executed in most cases. Isn't that more important than the number of branches made in your bytecode?

Comment: kind of lost as to what i should do with the post. Like @MikeRyan said, this post is flagged as opinion based. I did get the answere i was looking for thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should choose the version that's easier to understand - the second one. There won't be much difference in terms of performance, and you shouldn't try to optimize your code unless you really have to.